# Deleting Ubuntu 14.04 root partition has caused Ubuntu 16.04 to boot slower

Tags: 14.04, boot, 16.04, uninstall

I have three operating systems on my HDD: `Ubuntu 16.04` (my primary OS), `Ubuntu 14.04` and `Windows 10`. To make some space I wanted to uninstall (completely remove) `Ubuntu 14.04`. It doesn't have a separate `/home` partition so I went to `gparted` and deleted the `/` partition of `Ubuntu 14.04`, thinking this would completely remove `Ubuntu 14.04` from my system. But this doesn't seem to be the case since I still find `Ubuntu 14.04` in the boot-up GRUB menu.

**BUT, the real issue is:
 `Ubuntu 16.04` boot-up time has increased from the moment I did all this**. It now waits for about 1 minute on a purple screen and abot 20 more seconds on a deeper purple sccreen.

I do not know if the two events are linked, but the coincidence is making me doubt that.

Please suggest me a way to make my `Ubuntu 16.04` boot faster.

**EDIT**: My hardware specs are pretty good, so ~2-3min boot time is pretty long. (8GB DDR3 RAM and Intel core i7 5th gen at 2.4GHz)

**EDIT2**: `sudo update-grub` fixed the GRUB menu. Thanks Aditya!

**EDIT3**: `systemd-analyze blame` gave the following result:

```
      8.116s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-A26F\x2d13FF.service
      7.713s dev-sda5.device
      6.855s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-90593b0b\x2d38aa\x2d46c2\x2d8f
      2.843s NetworkManager.service
      2.020s accounts-daemon.service
      1.778s systemd-udevd.service
      1.739s thermald.service
      1.534s grub-common.service
      1.437s ModemManager.service
      1.402s plymouth-start.service
      1.347s lightdm.service
      1.075s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
       982ms keyboard-setup.service
       941ms systemd-rfkill.service
       892ms home.mount
       877ms apparmor.service
       834ms systemd-modules-load.service
       739ms plymouth-read-write.service
       611ms upower.service
       552ms ufw.service
       533ms irqbalance.service
       469ms systemd-logind.service
       461ms dev-mqueue.mount
       461ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       460ms systemd-journald.service
       459ms dev-hugepages.mount
       452ms ondemand.service
       448ms alsa-restore.service
       443ms gpu-manager.service
       440ms rsyslog.service
       439ms snapd.autoimport.service
       437ms systemd-user-sessions.service
       415ms avahi-daemon.service
       415ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       411ms colord.service
       410ms bluetooth.service
       373ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
       369ms apport.service
       293ms udisks2.service
       286ms boot-efi.mount
       275ms dev-sda6.swap
       267ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       243ms console-setup.service
       133ms wpa_supplicant.service
       102ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
        98ms binfmt-support.service
        91ms systemd-journal-flush.service
        88ms systemd-sysctl.service
        87ms systemd-remount-fs.service
        83ms polkitd.service
        81ms setvtrgb.service
        67ms networking.service
        53ms systemd-random-seed.service
        50ms systemd-update-utmp.service
        29ms user@1000.service
        25ms snapd.socket
        23ms speech-dispatcher.service
         4ms pppd-dns.service
         4ms ureadahead-stop.service
         4ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         3ms dns-clean.service
         3ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
         3ms resolvconf.service
         3ms rtkit-daemon.service
         1ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
         1ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
         1ms rc-local.service
```

Comment: Did you run `sudo update-grub` after removing the partition. This should remove the Ubuntu 14.04 Boot entry.

Comment: Also, what were the results of `systemd-analyze blame`?

Comment: Thanks @Aditya `sudo update-grub` fixed the GRUB menu.

Comment: So, how is the boot speed?

Comment: Sorry, boot-speed is still the same. About 3-4.5 minutes

Comment: The top three lines of `systemd-analyze blame` output, taking a lot of time, is about /dev/sda5 .. would that be your old 14.04 partition ? Do you have a line in /etc/fstab trying to mount it ?

Comment: In addition to Soren's tip, I have one too to speed up booting. Exclude partitions not explicitly required at boot time from auto-mounting. As you know, before the mount partitions are e2fsck-checked, which takes time. To illustrate, I excluded 2 partitions, each about 1TB, from auto-mounting and shaved of 45 seconds of boot-time.

Comment: @SorenA .. /dev/sda5 is the `/` partition of my `16.04`, not `14.04`.

Comment: @WillemK. Thanks, I'll try stopping my windows C: from auto-mounting.

Comment: @SorenA: In /etc/fstab it shows **two** swap partitions. One with a UUID that exists in my gparted, and the other with a UUID which doesn't exist in my gparted. Could that be causing the problem? Is it safe to comment out that non-existent swap-partition line in /etc/fstab? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I hope SorenA does mind me answering... ;-)  If that line for the non-existent swap-partition does NOT start with a #  then yes, remove it. The system will then no longer try to find that non-existing partition. Just for safety... check in gparted that the existing swap has 'swapon'.

Comment: Thanks @WillemK and SorenA . It works. :') Boot time is down to ~30 seconds. It's nearly the time it used to take (approx 20 seconds I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved in [the comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/909840/solved-deleting-ubuntu-14-04-root-partition-has-caused-ubuntu-16-04-to-boot-sl#comment1430444_909840) by @Soren A:

> @SorenA: In `/etc/fstab` it shows two swap partitions. One with a UUID that exists in my gparted, and the other with a UUID which doesn't exist in my gparted. Could that be causing the problem? Is it safe to comment out that non-existent swap-partition line in `/etc/fstab`? Thanks a lot! – [VP97](https://askubuntu.com/users/586050/vp97) [1 hour ago](https://askubuntu.com/questions/909840/solved-deleting-ubuntu-14-04-root-partition-has-caused-ubuntu-16-04-to-boot-sl#comment1430574_909840)
>
> I hope SorenA does mind me answering... ;-) If that line for the non-existent swap-partition does NOT start with a # then yes, remove it. The system will then no longer try to find that non-existing partition. Just for safety... check in gparted that the existing swap has 'swapon'. – [Willem K](https://askubuntu.com/users/680858/willem-k) [16 mins ago](https://askubuntu.com/questions/909840/solved-deleting-ubuntu-14-04-root-partition-has-caused-ubuntu-16-04-to-boot-sl#comment1430627_909840)